# QString contains and special characters

Tags: qt, special-characters, qstring

I've a `Qstring` that contains some characters and `'Å'`.

Using `MatchString.contains('Å')` it return false.

There is some mistake in my understanding of this function?

Comment: What does `MatchString.contains(QChar(0xc5))` produce?

Comment: I don't post it as answer, because solution was already found, but try to write: contains("Å")  With " ", not ' '. I think that in your case it will be work too.

Comment: Already tried it but unfortunatelly this solution doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get possibly differing results if your source file is not saved using UTF-8 encoding or if your platform does not support unsigned `char` types so explicitly create the `QChar` object using it's Unicode value:

```
if (MatchString.contains(QChar(0xc5))) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write `'Å'` a compiler treats it as an ASCII character while `Å` is a unicode character. So use `L'Å'` instead. Look here for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf.aspx

Also you may want to use `_T` macro which translates the literal string to the L-prefixed form is `_UNICODE` is defined.

Comment: That seems Windows-specific.